# Integration Sonar plugin with eclipse

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm trying to use Sonar plugin with eclipse projects, but when I go to my project and try to "Associate with Sonar" it doesnt work. It says that GroupID is empty. I've searched everywhere and didnt find an answer.

Comment: what happens when you click on "Find on Server"? Did you specifiy the right sonar server/instance in the drop down box?

Comment: When I click Find on Server. A Load bar appears and when the load stops nothing happens. I don't know if I specified the right server

Comment: You have to specify your own server/Server installation. You must have analysed your projects at least once, before using the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Did you click "find on server" like described here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+Eclipse ?
[image]

That usually worked for me if the same project is available at the sonar instance.
You should click finish only after the project was found on the server.

Comment: what if the server is not available in the sonar instance? How to manually add it?

Comment: @Rudy http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+Eclipse#SonarEclipse-ConfigureSonarEclipse

Comment: I think you don't understand my question. However I solved it. Thx.

Comment: @Rudy can you by chance elaborate on how you solved it? i am stuck here as well.

Comment: @JoeChen you can always ask a new question,but make sure that it is easily understood :D

Answer (score 0):

If your Sonar server requires authentication, make sure that the credentials are entered in "Window / Preferences / Sonar"
Otherwise, clicking on "Find on server" will not fill-in the GroupID/ArtifactID/Branch fields.